# angular global search only works without filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angularjs-scope

I have a global search and it works only if I show the data as its in the controller. But as soon as I apply a filter, the search does not find it.

So if I have a date timestamp like `1429138800` and I have this in view

```
{{ date }}
```

it will work

But when I add a filter to show shortdate like this `{{date | date:'shortDate'}}` and I try to search for `1/17` it wont work.... how can I make it searchable after applying filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know about how you implement your filter, but for making instance of your filtered data you can do this:

```
{{newDate = (date | date:'shortDate')}} -> "1/17"
{{newDate}} -> "1/17"
```

So now you can search your keyword in `newDate` instead of `date`.
Hope to help!

**Update:**
Or maybe you can write a custom filter and convert your data before repeating on them without harming your main data:

```
app.filter('toDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (a) {
      var b = angular.copy(a);
      for (var i=0, j=b.length; i<j; i++) {
        b[i] = $filter('date')(b[i], 'shortDate');
      }
      return b;
    }
}]);
```

And then use it like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in dates | toDate | filter:key">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("bodyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [
    new Date("2016/1/1").getTime(),
    new Date("2016/1/2").getTime(),
    new Date("2016/1/3").getTime(),
    new Date("2016/1/4").getTime(),
    new Date("2016/1/5").getTime(),
    ]
}])
.filter('toDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (a) {
      var b = angular.copy(a);
      for (var i=0, j=b.length; i<j; i++) {
        b[i] = $filter('date')(b[i], 'shortDate');
      }
      return b;
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="key">
    <hr>
    Without toDate Filter
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in dates | filter:key">{{item | date:"shortDate"}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    With toDate Filter
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in dates | toDate | filter:key">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: do I just need this {{newDate}} -> "1/17" is -> a syntax? what does it do?

Comment: your with and without dates are same?

Comment: @Autolycus you have to type in that input to see the result! type "1/2" without quote.